# How to deal with the recent Azure outage (Azure Websites)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have TONS of websites hosted on Azure.  Our VMs appear to be running now, but many of our Azure Websites are not.  In an effort to bring our sites back up sooner than later, we have tried scaling UP, OUT, and changing our hosting plan, to no avail.  Is there a way to force an Azure Website VM to move to another (working) datacenter?  We don't want to destroy the site and bring it back up, as we will be forced to update DNS, which will cause an even longer delay in service to our customers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sorry to everyone else experiencing a long night right along with me.

Comment: According to the status updates, it looks like they're basically coming back online again... http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to run two instances of the site in two Regions and use something like Traffic Manager (or AWS Route 53 if you want something external to Azure) to perform failover routing for you.

Depending on the type of sites you could run a static holding site in a non-Azure environment and failover to that. How you choose to solve this will depend on what your budget is (or opportunity cost in the event your sites are offline).

Note that a 99.9% yearly SLA equates to almost 9 hours of downtime in a year.

If you want to understand how you could solve this intra-Azure here's a good guide: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/03/deploy-an-ultra-high-availablity-mvc-web-app-on-microsoft-azure-part-1/

Comment: Based on the Azure status site last night and the description here: http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2014/11/19/microsoft-azure-suffering-widespread-outage/ , I don't think redundancy within two Azure regions would actually have helped, unless you happened to get really lucky and have chosen one of the few regions that was still working. As Simon mentioned, a static site outside Azure could at least show something like a maintenance page, and be really cheap to host. I've used http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/dns-failover-system-monitoring/ for this before with success.

Comment: We actually discussed using Traffic Manager (going forward) today, and the question popped up:  "What if Traffic Manager datacenters went down"?  I'm assuming they have built-in failovers to prevent downtime, but I would hate to add another potential point of failure to the mix.  I can't find any information about "guaranteed uptime" with regard to Traffic Manager.  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/

Comment: Traffic Manager offers a 99.99% SLA to respond to DNS queries (it's ultimately all DNS-based). DNS is an inherently distributable part of the internet so your chances are pretty slim this would be a problem. If you want comfort then look at AWS Route53 which offers a 100% uptime SLA. Note that an SLA doesn't mean an outage can't happen, just that you have some financial recourse if it does.