# How to deal with Azure Outages, current one was a network drop between websites and SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We just suffered a SQL Database connectivity issue on Azure. Although very quick, around 1 minute, it did kick all users out, and/or raised Elmah Errors such as:

```
The wait operation timed out ...

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection
```

Even glitches like this compromises confidence. I am trying to understand about good approaches to confront these transitory outages. Some thoughts that come to mind include:

1. Have some code that checks that all required services are running before using them and keep checking with provide friendly error message until they are. I think there is a tendency to assume all is available and working, and I wonder whether this is a dangerous assumption in the world of cloud. I suppose this is more an approach one would take when building a distributed application, although one may not for a database which is usually close to the web application.
2. Use failover procedures such as TrafficManager. However it is expensive as one now has >1 instance and also one needs to take care of the syncing data across >1 DB etc. [Associated link on Failover procedure in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008978/how-to-deal-with-the-recent-azure-outage-azure-websites)
3. Make sure Custom Error pages are used so Yellow Screen of death (YSOD) is not seen:

   ```
   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error" />
   ```

Although YSOD was seen by a colleague, not sure how with the above in force. Once criticism I have of Azure is that if Websites are down, then one can get bad error pages, only provided by Azure and not customisable, although I was advised that using something like CloudFlare can sort this issue.

I think a) is the most interesting concept. Should we code Azure Web Apps as if they are WAN rather than LAN applications, and assume nodes could be down, and so check beforehand?

I would really appreciate thoughts on the above. Our feeling is that Azure is getting a few too many of these outage blips now, which may be due to increased customers... not sure. Although no doubt within the 99.9% annual SLA.

EDIT1

A useful MSDN Azure Cloud Architecture article on this:

[Resilient Azure Website Architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn787017.aspx)

Comment: Many possiblities, no single right answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon for the reply. I see that you are an expert in this area, so some hints, on "Many possiblities" would be helpful, or a pointer to information on this. Perhaps 5 bullet points. I am sure others would find this most useful. Thanks..

Comment: I have found something that might be of interest to all. See EDIT 1

Comment: Take a look at the transient fault handling application block: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440719(v=pandp.60).aspx

Comment: Thanks @StevenBerkovitz, This looks useful. All new to me, although the idea is not, and seems entirely sensible, basically assume that service is not there.

Comment: A 1min outage is not a transient error. It will always be user-visible.

Comment: To me there are 2 options. Firstly one can switch across to another instance in another data centre using Traffic Manager, or secondly check that all required resources are functioning before executing task, and if not functioning, report back to browser using something like AJAX ??? Perhaps keep retrying , or ask user to resubmit when "server less busy/available". I suspect the 2nd option is simpler and cheaper.

Comment: After speaking to different people, my conclusion on this is to check for a transient error, and if it is still present then to return a message back to the user, providing a friendly message and ask them to retry in a few minutes. At the moment I feel we do not warrant the extra cost and logistics of a multi instance traffic manager setup. If Azure Websites is down then I guess we could use a pre websites redirection service like Cloudflare to provide professional feedback to the end user.